# Return a shallow list copy in getters and how getters work in general

Tags: java, list, arraylist, getter-setter, shallow-copy

I not sure how creating a shallow copy in the getters actually work and how it will benefit us.

Does it still function as a normal getter in that I can retrieve the information in that list whenever I call the getter method?

I'm worried about this because in the future if I call
`this.strings` and `this.getStrings()`
they result in different outputs that'll be trouble.

And I guess there's an implicit question here,

I've been mulling over this for some time:

As in the example below, some people would just call `strings` to get the information in that list (as in this case it's private so I suppose it'll work just fine?), where others go about calling `this.strings` or `this.getStrings`.

I'm a beginner in java so all these appear to be able to achieve the same outcome, which makes me so confused.

Could anyone explain? Sorry if the wording is not clear.

Code is provided below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Experiment {

    private List<String> strings;

    public Experiment(String string) {
        this.strings = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<String> getStrings() {
        return strings;
    }

}
```

Some programmer do not implement:

```
public List<String> getStrings() {
        return strings;
}
```

Instead they do:

```
public List<String> getStrings() {
        return new ArrayList<>(strings);
}
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy) is the difference between the two types of copy.

Answer (score 1):

First code returns a shallow copy of `strings`. The returned reference points to the same object of `ArrayList` as the reference stored in `strings`. Changes made through both of them will affect the same object.

Second code creates a new object of `ArrayList` and returns a reference pointing to it. The new object has the same elements as the `List` in strings.

> ArrayList(Collection c)
>   Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.

A new object is created so the changes in the returned `List` won't affect the `List` in `strings`.

Comment: To the OP: An easy way to see this is just to try it.